# How to do a page break in crystal reports when next group won't fit on current page?

Tags: c#, .net, crystal-reports, sections

Hello I have the following report that is generated on CR.
I have the same file in a couple of sites, but each returns a different pdf despite sending the same data:

Example 1:

[image]

Example 2 :

[image]

As you can see, in the second example, once one of the tickets finishes, another one starts after it on the very bottom, which makes it incomplete.

In the first example, it automatically sends it to the next page once it finds that the next one won't fit in the current page.

I can't seem to remember what I did to fix that, nor I understand why do I get different results in two different sites using the same rpt file with the same provided data.

Answer (score 1):

Check `new page after` option im the section expert of the group so that new group starts on a new page

Answer (score 0):

You say "I get different results in two different sites", means 2 different browser?

The output of same file will always comes same, first thing. Second is you just give your page margin of header- footer much more from the ticket size, so give always same result.

It may be some height issue at execution time, it give different result. So safer side , give as much as height and low-margin of page by report option -> page size.